# How do I query a many to many relationship model? - Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, many-to-many, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

Here are my models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    link = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class UserPage(db.Model): 
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name='pages') 
    page = db.ReferenceProperty(Page, collection_name='users')
```

How would I construct a query to find a users pages?

I found an article that describes a method to do it but is this the best way? http://blog.arbingersys.com/2008/04/google-app-engine-better-many-to-many.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer will work, but it will perform 7 calls to the datastore:

- 1 for the call to User.get_by_key_name()
- 1 for the call to UserPage...fetch()
- 5 for each dereference of x.page.id inside the loop

An alternative approach which only does 3 calls to the datastore would be something like this:

```
myuser = User.get_by_key_name("1") 
up = UserPage.all().filter('user =', myuser).fetch(5)
keys = [UserPage.page.get_value_for_datastore(x) for x in up]
pages = db.get(keys)
for p in pages: 
     self.response.out.write(p.id)
```

See http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine for more details.

Comment: oh very nice! I wasn't aware of the loop being so expensive. Thx for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, it appears I can use:

```
 myuser = User.get_by_key_name("1")
 up = UserPage.all().filter('user =', myuser).fetch(5)
 for x in up:
     self.response.out.write(x.page.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a different approach, that is less "relational-oriented" than your `UserPage` relationship:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.StringProperty()

class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    link = db.StringProperty(required=True)

    # Users linking to this page
    users = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

And then you can get all pages of a specific user with the following query:

```
Page.gql("WHERE users = :1", user.key())
```

Please note that you should place the list property of keys on the side where you expect less items. I've assumed you will have less users liked to a page, than pages linked to a user, so I've put it on the `Page` side, but that will depend on your specific use case.

See here for official recommendations on the many-to-many topic: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html

Comment: Thx for this approach and for the article. I'll do some testing with it.

Comment: Thanks again for this, I ended up going with this approach.